# Generic filenames in Makefile

Tags: makefile, latex

How to catch numeric suffixes in filenames in makefile? More precisely, I have a book written in latex and split by multiple chapter files, I wanted to write a makefile that supports the following syntax, for compiling the whole book:

```
make book
```

for individual chapter:

```
make chapter_1
```

for example. My files are `book.tex` with several lines `\include{chapter_i}` and multiple number of `chapter_i.tex` files where `i` is a chapter number.

Thanks to all!

Comment: You cannot compile individual LaTeX chapters if they are not included in a document.. How do you achieve this without make?

Comment: I write `\include{chapter_i}` in `book.tex`. And I know that there is a command `\includeonly{chapter_i}` to compile book with only one included chapter. Moreover, there is a syntax for `pdflatex` that can handle such things: `pdflatex -jobname=chapter "\includeonly{chapter_i}\input{book}"`, which compiles book with only one chapter. I don't know how to write a makefile that can recognize this pattern `chapter_i` for each chapter.

Answer (score 0):

[Pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) and/or [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) are what you are looking for:

```
CHAPTERS      := $(wildcard chapter_*.tex)
CHAPTER_PDFS  := $(patsubst %.tex,%.pdf,$(CHAPTERS))
SHORT_TARGETS := book $(patsubst %.pdf,%,$(CHAPTER_PDFS))

.PHONY: all $(SHORT_TARGETS)

all: book

$(SHORT_TARGETS): %: %.pdf

book.pdf: book.tex $(CHAPTERS)
    pdflatex $<

$(CHAPTER_PDFS): chapter_%.pdf: chapter_%.tex book.tex
    pdflatex -jobname=chapter_$* "\includeonly{chapter_$*}\input{book}"
```

Note: in the recipes (and only in the recipes) the `$*` automatic variable expands as the matching pattern of the rule. So, for `chapter_42`, for instance, the last rule means:

```
chapter_42.pdf: chapter_42.tex book.tex
    pdflatex -jobname=chapter_42 "\includeonly{chapter_42}\input{book}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll test it later.